# mupdf continuous scrolling

Tags: windows, pdf, scrolling

I use mupdf and I like it a lot, because I'm a vim-addict. One thing bugs me: There is no continuous scrolling. When you reach the end of a page and scroll further, then it "jumps" to the next page.

Is there a way to enable continuous scrolling?

I found http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693425 and there it is written that you can use SHIFT+C to enable it. But this only makes the display yellow.

I use it on Windows 10 if this is relevant, but since it is mainly a unix tool, I ask the question here.

Comment: Reading that bug report, I'd guess shift+C enables it when that specific patch is applied, but said patch is not part of `mupdf`. I've looked into this recently: it seems that there is no continuous scrolling in `mupdf` and that [they are not interested in adding it (WONTFIX on a different bug)](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=697213).

Comment: On Linux you could use Zathura, but unfortunately, there is no Windows version, afaik.

Answer (score 4):

There is an PDF pager based off of mupdf that has exactly what you want:
http://repo.or.cz/w/llpp.git

(Some unix OS'es might have an easy way to install it, for example Arch Linux has the package in the Arch User Repository: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/llpp/)

Comment: You need to build it yourself. I have no idea how hard this is on Windows 10. Let us know how that works out..